# OpenSSL i2d_ECPrivateKey() crashes

Tags: c, openssl, elliptic-curve

I have the following program. It successfully obtains the raw 32 byte EC private key data and then creates a EC_KEY from it. But i2d_ECPrivateKey fails to give the size of the DER encoded private key, as it crashes. Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

```
#include "CBWIF.h"
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    CBWIF wif;

    if (argc != 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Decode WIF string
    CBByteArray str;
    CBInitByteArrayFromString(&str, argv[1], false);
    CBInitWIFFromString(&wif, &str, false);
    CBDestroyByteArray(&str);

    // Get key
    uint8_t key[32];
    CBWIFGetPrivateKey(&wif, key);
    CBDestroyWIF(&wif);

    // Create OpenSSL key

    EC_KEY * eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
    BIGNUM * bn = BN_bin2bn(key, CB_PRIVKEY_SIZE, NULL);
    if (!EC_KEY_set_private_key(eckey, bn)) 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Convert key to DER format

    int len = i2d_ECPrivateKey(eckey, NULL); // <-- CRASH HERE  
    unsigned char derkey[len];
    i2d_ECPrivateKey(eckey, (unsigned char **)&derkey);

    EC_KEY_free(eckey);

    // Encode DER key as hex

    char out[len*2+1];  
    CBBytesToString(derkey, 0, len, out, false);

    // Print to stdout      
    puts(out);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`CB_PRIVKEY_SIZE` is 32. I verified that the key data from `CBWIFGetPrivateKey` is correct. The program crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff766cb03 in EC_POINT_point2oct () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#1  0x00007ffff7658124 in i2d_ECPrivateKey () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x0000000000400bf6 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe038) at examples/WIF2DER.c:46
```

Comment: I just came across this from OpenBSD's Vahalla project: [Avoid a NULL dereference in `i2d_ECPrivateKey()` when an EC_KEY lacks the public key member](https://secure.freshbsd.org/commit/openbsd/a584c40d5b0c3c4d5b57ba3007b94f949b6b7565).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you cannot run i2d_ECPrivateKey without setting a public key, probably due to a bug in OpenSSL. I generated the public key and solved a few other issues an now the program works:

```
#include "CBWIF.h"
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    CBWIF wif;

    if (argc != 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Decode WIF string
    CBByteArray str;
    CBInitByteArrayFromString(&str, argv[1], false);
    CBInitWIFFromString(&wif, &str, false);
    CBDestroyByteArray(&str);

    // Get key
    uint8_t key[32];
    CBWIFGetPrivateKey(&wif, key);
    CBDestroyWIF(&wif);

    // Create OpenSSL key
    EC_KEY * eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
    BIGNUM * bn = BN_bin2bn(key, CB_PRIVKEY_SIZE, NULL);

    if (!EC_KEY_set_private_key(eckey, bn)) 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Create public key as OpenSSL cannot do this easily
    EC_GROUP * group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
    EC_POINT * point = EC_POINT_new(group);
    BN_CTX * ctx = BN_CTX_new();

    EC_POINT_mul(group, point, bn, NULL, NULL, ctx);

    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    EC_GROUP_free(group);
    BN_free(bn);

    if (!EC_KEY_set_public_key(eckey, point))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    EC_POINT_free(point);

    // Check the key
    if (!EC_KEY_check_key(eckey))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Convert key to DER format
    int len = i2d_ECPrivateKey(eckey, NULL);    
    unsigned char derkey[len];
    unsigned char * derkeyPtr = derkey;
    i2d_ECPrivateKey(eckey, &derkeyPtr);

    // Freeing the EC_KEY here crashes for some reason???

    // Encode DER key as hex

    char out[len*2+1];  
    CBBytesToString(derkey, 0, len, out, false);

    // Print to stdout
    puts(out);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how OpenSSL uses it in `<openssl src/crypto/ec/ec_ameth.c`. All the other similar uses in the library utilize `i2d_ECPrivateKey_bio`. Also, you might take a quick look at how the `OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE` flag is used with `V_ASN1_OBJECT`.

```
unsigned char   *ep, *p;
int         eplen, ptype;
unsigned int    tmp_flags, old_flags;
...

old_flags = EC_KEY_get_enc_flags(ec_key);
tmp_flags = old_flags | EC_PKEY_NO_PARAMETERS;
...

eplen = i2d_ECPrivateKey(ec_key, NULL);
if (!eplen)
{
    EC_KEY_set_enc_flags(ec_key, old_flags);
    ECerr(EC_F_ECKEY_PRIV_ENCODE, ERR_R_EC_LIB);
    return 0;
}
ep = (unsigned char *) OPENSSL_malloc(eplen);
if (!ep)
{
    EC_KEY_set_enc_flags(ec_key, old_flags);
    ECerr(EC_F_ECKEY_PRIV_ENCODE, ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
    return 0;
}
p = ep;
if (!i2d_ECPrivateKey(ec_key, &p))
{
    EC_KEY_set_enc_flags(ec_key, old_flags);
    OPENSSL_free(ep);
    ECerr(EC_F_ECKEY_PRIV_ENCODE, ERR_R_EC_LIB);
    return 0;
}
...
```

---

Also take a look at [Avoid a NULL dereference in `i2d_ECPrivateKey()` when an EC_KEY lacks the public key member](https://secure.freshbsd.org/commit/openbsd/a584c40d5b0c3c4d5b57ba3007b94f949b6b7565) from OpenBSD's LibReSSL project.